# Relationship Between Convolution and Fourier Analysis

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution

While I am reading a lecture note about a rendering of lighting and its reflection on surfaces, I've found the following change of formula using Fourier Analysis

[image]

The author appended the following slides too, but can't understand how to formula converted with those hints.

Any hint for good starting of understanding this conversion?

The full lecture note is available at [link](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/16823-s16/www/pdfs/appearance-modeling-7-8.pdf)

[image]

Comment: The Fourier transform of a convolution is a product and vice versa:
$$\widehat{f*g} = \hat f \cdot \hat g$$
(with some factor depending of what definition of Fourier transform is being used.)

Comment: Only for circular convolution which the above is not.

Comment: @md2perpe product of what?

Comment: @Beverlie. The Fourier transform of convolution of two functions is the product of the Fourier transforms of the two functions.

Comment: @mathreadler. What kind of convolution is this? I don't want to deep-dive into the formulas right now.

Comment: @md2perpe only for circular convolution. The above is not a circular convolution.

Comment: @mathreadler. You have already said that. But what kind of convolution is this?